# R `scales::percent_format` outputs the function definition instead of the answer

Tags: r, scale

This code chunk works fine:

```
scales::percent(c(0.1, 0.9))
#> [1] "10.0%" "90.0%"
```

This code chunk does not:

```
scales::percent_format(c(0.1, 0.9), accuracy = 4)
#> function (x) 
#> number(x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix, 
#>     suffix = suffix, big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark, 
#>     trim = trim, ...)
#> <bytecode: 0x5636327990a0>
#> <environment: 0x56362dadd470>
```

What's wrong with my percent_format `accuracy` argument? It usually works fine and doesn't output the function?? I'd expect the output to be something like:

```
#> [1] "10.0000%" "90.0000%"
```

Comment: As described on the  `?percent_format` help page, the `_format` versions of the functions return functions, not character values. Why not just use `scales::percent(c(0.1, 0.9), accuracy = 4)`?

Comment: if you really wanted to use `percent_format` you can just do `scales::percent_format(accuracy = 4)(c(0.1, 0.9))`

Comment: Also I think you are using `accuracy=` incorrectly. I think you want `scales::percent(c(0.1, 0.9), accuracy=.0001)`